# Promtail : context deadline exceeded

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I have deployed loki in a kubernetes cluster "A" and trying to push the logs via promtail from another kubernetes cluster "B" to the loki endpoint (A).

Below is the client URL set in promtail configuration

http://example.com/loki/api/v1/push

example.com is the ingress resource for the loki-distributed-gateway service (A ).

Getting below exception in the promtail pod logs

`level=warn ts=2023-07-03T12:14:39.999147998Z caller=client.go:419 component=client host=example.com msg="error sending batch, will retry" status=-1 tenant= error="Post \"http://example.com/loki/api/v1/push\": context deadline exceeded" level=warn ts=2023-07-03T12:16:08.855915577Z caller=client.go:419 component=client host=example.com msg="error sending batch, will retry" status=-1 tenant= error="Post \"http://example.com/loki/api/v1/push\": context deadline exceeded"`